# cant run bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load In my github actions

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, github-actions

i'm trying to run bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load in my github actions, but get following error:

```
Run bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "::1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Couldn't create 'novem_test' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "::1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "::1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I am using image: postgres:latest in my jobs too. what can be causing this? i've been stuck on this error.

Tried all the solutions i could find, nothing helped.

Comment: Please include your workflow in your question. [PostgreSQL is presintalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#postgresql) on GHA-hosted runners. You just need to start it.